# Strange CONNECTIVITY_ACTION Behavior

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

This post may seem long.. But it's very simple. So please please help. Thanks.

**In short words, Whenever there is Connectivity change from Wifi to Mobile, I receive a message in my Broadcast receiver 2 times(First time NO Network is found). And when I move from Mobile to Wifi, I receive it three times. Can anyone please explain me this strange behavior.**

I have implemented a code using IntentFilterConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) and registered it to my receiver.

IntentFilter mNetworkStateFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);

```
registerReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver , mNetworkStateFilter);


private final BroadcastReceiver mNetworkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
          {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {
                  //The Network State has Been Changed
                  Log.d(TAG, "CHANGE HAPPENED" );

                 if (networkInfo != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected To: " + networkInfo.getTypeName());
            Log.d(TAG, "NUMBER: " + networkInfo.getType());
            Log.d(TAG, "isConnectedOrConnecting: " + networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
            Log.d(TAG, "isConnected: " + networkInfo.isConnected());
            Log.d(TAG, "isFailover: " + networkInfo.isFailover());
            Log.d(TAG, "Reason :" + networkInfo.getReason());
            Log.d(TAG, "Details " + networkInfo.getDetailedState() );


            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);



            Log.d(TAG, "noConnectivity: " + noConnectivity);
            Log.d(TAG, "reason: " + reason);

            Log.d(TAG,"DONE");

        }       


            }
      };
```

I have observed the following behavior. Can anyone please explain the reason for this happening.

Initially My Device is connected to Wifi.

The APK is now Deployed on the Device.

My Logcat entry is 
D/MainActivity(32005): CHANGE HAPPENED
D/MainActivity(32005): Connected to WIFI

This is understandable.

Now the Router is turned off. So now the device attempts to connect to 4G.
Now, the Logcat Entry is as follows.

D/MainActivity(32005): CHANGE HAPPENED
D/MainActivity(32005): CHANGE HAPPENED
D/MainActivity(32005): Connected to Mobile

May be this can be attributed to the fact the first the connection is broken, which causes CHANGE HAPPENED to be printed but not the Message “Connected to “. And then the connection is established with Mobile resulting in another CHANGE HAPPENED with Connected to Mobile.

Now the router is turned on again.

But this time the logcat reports,
D/MainActivity(32005): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(32005): Connected to WIFI

D/MainActivity(32005): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(32005): Connected to WIFI

D/MainActivity(32005): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(32005): Connected to WIFI

I am not able to understand why the Logcat reported this message three times. Can anyone please help me understand this behavior.

This is my manisfest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wififourghandoff"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

THIS IS MY OBSERVATION.

Is the Sequence like the Following :

Wifi to Mobile : 
1. Network Info is NULL
2. Netowrk Info object Exists and the "reason(networkInfo.getReason()" is dataEnabled.

From Mobile to Wifi : 
1. Broadcast Message Received.
2. Netowrk Info object Exists and the "reason(networkInfo.getReason()" is dataDisabled. 
3. NetworkInfo with Exists withe "reason(networkInfo.getReason()"  as null

**MY Device is Camped on to WIFI Initially
My Logcat**

D/MainActivity(  880): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(  880): Connected To: WIFI

D/MainActivity(  880): NUMBER: 1

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnectedOrConnecting: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnected: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isFailover: false

D/MainActivity(  880): Reason :null

D/MainActivity(  880): Details CONNECTED

D/MainActivity(  880): noConnectivity: false

D/MainActivity(  880): reason: null

D/MainActivity(  880): DONE

**NOW WIFI is Turned OFF. So Now My device moves into MOBILE. Following is the Logcat.**

D/MainActivity(  880): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(  880): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(  880): Connected To: mobile

D/MainActivity(  880): NUMBER: 0

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnectedOrConnecting: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnected: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isFailover: true

D/MainActivity(  880): Reason :dataEnabled

D/MainActivity(  880): Details CONNECTED

D/MainActivity(  880): noConnectivity: false

D/MainActivity(  880): reason: dataEnabled

D/MainActivity(  880): DONE

**NOW my WIFI is turned on. And my device camps back to Wifi.**

D/MainActivity(  880): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(  880): Connected To: WIFI

D/MainActivity(  880): NUMBER: 1

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnectedOrConnecting: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnected: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isFailover: false

D/MainActivity(  880): Reason :null

D/MainActivity(  880): Details CONNECTED

D/MainActivity(  880): noConnectivity: false

D/MainActivity(  880): reason: null

D/MainActivity(  880): DONE

D/MainActivity(  880): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(  880): Connected To: WIFI

D/MainActivity(  880): NUMBER: 1

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnectedOrConnecting: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnected: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isFailover: false

D/MainActivity(  880): Reason :null

D/MainActivity(  880): Details CONNECTED

D/MainActivity(  880): noConnectivity: false

D/MainActivity(  880): reason: dataDisabled

D/MainActivity(  880): DONE

D/MainActivity(  880): CHANGE HAPPENED

D/MainActivity(  880): Connected To: WIFI

D/MainActivity(  880): NUMBER: 1

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnectedOrConnecting: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isConnected: true

D/MainActivity(  880): isFailover: false

D/MainActivity(  880): Reason :null

D/MainActivity(  880): Details CONNECTED

D/MainActivity(  880): noConnectivity: false

D/MainActivity(  880): reason: null

D/MainActivity(  880): DONE

Thanks & Regards,
Yuvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you log the `Extra` content the behavior might make more sense:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

> A change in network connectivity has occurred. A connection has either been established or lost. The NetworkInfo for the affected network is sent as an extra; it should be consulted to see what kind of connectivity event occurred.
>
> If this is a connection that was the result of failing over from a disconnected network, then the FAILOVER_CONNECTION boolean extra is set to true.
>
> For a loss of connectivity, if the connectivity manager is attempting to connect (or has already connected) to another network, the NetworkInfo for the new network is also passed as an extra. This lets any receivers of the broadcast know that they should not necessarily tell the user that no data traffic will be possible. Instead, the reciever should expect another broadcast soon, indicating either that the failover attempt succeeded (and so there is still overall data connectivity), or that the failover attempt failed, meaning that all connectivity has been lost.
>
> For a disconnect event, the boolean extra EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY is set to true if there are no connected networks at all.

My Interpretation of what is going on with the three events when WiFi is enabled:

1. First event is simply informing you that WiFi is enabled.
2. Second event is informing you that the cellular network connection is
   disabled and that there is another available network (WiFi).  This
   is the event that has the NetworkInfo.
3. This is essentially a duplicate of event 1.  Whenever a disconnected event happens with a NetworkInfo, Android promises that it will follow up with a connection success/failure event for the network in the NetworkInfo

So, it's a little redundant for you, but this is normal behavior for the Android.  Here are some logs from my experiment:

```
    08-14 10:58:04.498: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): Bundle[{networkInfo=NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, inetCondition=0}]
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): Bundle[{extraInfo=VZWINTERNET, otherNetwork=NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, reason=dataDisabled, networkInfo=NetworkInfo: type: mobile[LTE], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: dataDisabled, extra: VZWINTERNET, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, inetCondition=0}]
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): ***********Network Info ******
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): Connected To: WIFI
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): Network Type: 1
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): isConnectedOrConnecting: true
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): isConnected: true
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): isFailover: false
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): Reason :null
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): Details: CONNECTED
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): noConnectivity: false
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): reason: dataDisabled
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): ******************************
    08-14 10:58:04.779: DEBUG/WiFiBroadcastReceiver(9161): Bundle[{networkInfo=NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, inetCondition=0}]
```

Comment: I am sorry. I have still not be able to figure the root cause for this issue. :( ...

Comment: Please share what you found was contained in the `Extra`s.

Comment: Is the Sequence like the Following :

Wifi to Mobile : 
1. Network Info is NULL
2. Netowrk Info object Exists and the "reason(networkInfo.getReason()" is dataEnabled. 


From Mobile to Wifi : 
1. Broadcast Message Received.
2. Netowrk Info object Exists and the "reason(networkInfo.getReason()" is dataDisabled. 
3. NetworkInfo with Exists withe "reason(networkInfo.getReason()"  as null

Comment: You can edit the question with these details.  They will help new readers solve your problem more easily that way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.. I wish I could vote up the answer... But poor reputation. :( ...

Comment: Hi, you are allowed (and encouraged) to accept an answer to your question if you feel that there was an answer.  There will be a check-mark next to the answer you can use.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask for instructions.  Best to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could examine `NetworkInfo` which is sent as an extra.

It might be that it's receiving failover message, as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) - when it fails for the first time, receives the message and then successfully connects again.

> For a loss of connectivity, if the connectivity manager is attempting
>   to connect (or has already connected) to another network, the
>   NetworkInfo for the new network is also passed as an extra. This lets
>   any receivers of the broadcast know that they should not necessarily
>   tell the user that no data traffic will be possible. Instead, the
>   reciever should expect another broadcast soon, indicating either that
>   the failover attempt succeeded (and so there is still overall data
>   connectivity), or that the failover attempt failed, meaning that all
>   connectivity has been lost.

Comment: I am sorry. I have still not be able to figure the root cause for this issue. :( ...